# rollup: how to require json but not include it in bundle

Tags: node.js, rollupjs

I have a `json` file that is required somewhere in my `node` script, but I do **not** want to have it bundled by `rollup`. I want it to be treated as an "external". Every time the `json` file changes, the script should be able to pick up the changes without rebuilding the bundle by rollup. Currently, it is "hard coded" in the bundle:

```js
// ./src/index.js
const json = require('../example.json');
```

with `./example.json` as:

```
{
    "exampleValue": "X"
}
```

returns a bundle that includes:

```js
// ...
var exampleValue = "X";
var example = {
    exampleValue: exampleValue
};

var example$1 = /*#__PURE__*/Object.freeze({
    exampleValue: exampleValue,
    default: example
});
// ...
```

I've tried to exclude it with [`rollup-plugin-json`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-json), but as I could have expected, it throws:

> [!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need rollup-plugin-json to import JSON files)

Is it possible to mark a json file as external, the same way you can mark external packages through the `external` and `output.paths` proeprties in the rollup configuration file?

Comment: Any news on this? I don't really understand why it would even do that and not just keep it like `var json = {"exampleValue": "x"}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [json plugin](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/json) actually does the job for me. Here is my configuration file `rollup-config.js`:

```js
// import json from 'rollup-plugin-json'; Deprecated
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import pkg from './package.json';


export default [
    // browser-friendly UMD build
    {
        input: './index.js',
        output: {
            file: '../index.js',
            name: 'Hy52fWS8r', // The global (never used) name for the factory of this UMD
            format: 'umd'
        },
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            json({
                compact: true
            })
        ]
    }
];
```

Source code:

```json
// test.json
[1, 2, 3]
```

```js
// index.js
const test = require('./test.json')
console.log(test) // Array(3) [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

The `rollup`'s output looks as follows:

```js
var test = [1,2,3];

var test$1 = /*#__PURE__*/Object.freeze({
    'default': test
});

var test$2 = getCjsExportFromNamespace(test$1);
```

I don't know yet what is the rationale behind this. You can just ignore the `test$1` and `test$2` variables.

Comment: Btw rollup-plugin-json is deprecated. You should use the new one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-json

Comment: A couple of notes for people who might try to get this working with TypeScript. You need to supply commonjs with the ".ts" extension as well, for example `commonjs({ extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] })`. Took me ages to figure out why this wasn't working.

Comment: any idea how to get it to not bundle it in `@rollup/plugin-json`,  @SabriMeviş ? Having the same issue as OP but in the contemporary version, and the docs still dont say.

Comment: I don't get the desired behavior with either `rollup-plugin-json` or `@rollup/plugin-json` currently. It bundles the json and there's no `getCjsExportFromNamespace` or `Object.freeze` occurring in the bundle.

Comment: How is this marked as the right answer? this still bundles json, does not mark is as external

Answer (score 0):

@Dmitry's answer does not address the question, to whoever comes looking for the answer:

Firstly rollup will hardcode all values it finds, so e.g.

```js
import {name, version} from '../package.json';
```

will get rolled up irrespective if you mark it external or not. In order to fix that, you can do:

```js
async function foo() {
  const {name, version} = await import('../package.json');
  // ...
}
```

This will prevent values from being hardcoded but would bundle `package.json` values anyways.

To mark it as external, in your `rollup.config.js` do:

```js
    // ...
    external: [
      // ...
      '../package.json' // exact match
      // ...
    ]
    // ...
```

This will change on how and where you import the json file. I tried with some implementation of wildcard externals, but that didn't work, maybe we can write for json.

But things since Node v17.5 have changed, since it will now drop ERR_IMPORT_ASSERTION_TYPE_MISSING error when bringing JSON files in.

you can have something like this:

```js
async function foo() {
  const {name, version} = await import('../package.json', { assert: { type: 'json' } });
  // ...
}
```

You can also read the file and parse it as JSON, which worked for me:

```js
function loadPkgInfo() {
    const pkgFile = join(process.cwd(), 'package.json');
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pkgFile).toString());
}
```

Comment: My answer is marked as a correct one for the reason it's true. If you read what `@rollup/plugin-json` does you can see that you've invented a wheel. Please, correct me if I'm wrong, I might be mistaken too.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same problem today. In the first few tries I put my json file into "external", but still got it built into final output. Then it occurred to me that, maybe I need to make that json file into a module first, then exclude it later. And the following worked for me.

1. Use "@rollup/plugin-json", so rollup can make that json into a module

   ```
   import json from '@rollup/plugin-json'
   ```
2. Grab that json file location

   ```
   const someJsonFile = join(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), 'pathToTheJsonFile')
   ```
3. Put it in external

   ```
   const optForRollup = {
     inputOptions: {
       input: 'entryFile',
       plugins: [
         nodeResolve(),
         commonjs(),
         json(),
       ],
       external: [
         /node_modules/,
         someJsonFile,
       ],
     },
     outputOptions: {
       file: 'targetFile',
       format: 'es',
       sourcemap: true,
       paths: {
         [someJsonFile]: './some.json', // specify where that json is in runtime environment
       }
     },
   }
   ```